# <shiro:hasPermission> condition check with two expression

Tags: jsp, shiro

I have two expressions: `<%=ABC.XYZ%>` & `<%=ABC.DEF%>` in shiro expression. Now if any of these conditions will match , will proceed further.

Suppose for single condition I am showing this as below:

```
shiro:hasPermission name="<%=ABC.XYZ%>" 

//will proceed further.
```

Now for both expression (`<%=ABC.XYZ%>` and `<%=ABC.DEF%>`), how I can write it?

I have tried as below, but to no success.

```
shiro:hasPermission name="<%=ABC.XYZ%>,<%=ABC.DEF%>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the conditions.

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="ABC">
    <shiro:hasPermission name="DEF">
        <h:outputLabel value="TEST"/>
    </shiro:hasPermission>
</shiro:hasPermission>
```

But be carefull with the use of shiro tags.

[Shiro Tags](http://shiro.apache.org/jsp-tag-library.html)

It should be used for simple checks. For more complex conditions, do something like this:

```
<h:outputLabel value="TEST" rendered="#{managedBean.hasPermission}"/>
```

And the make the complex logic using shiro on the java.

Comment: This is an AND, I think the OP asks for an OR